# MySQL Foreign Key Prevents Deleting Table — But Table is Empty

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Why would dropping an empty table produce a foreign key error?

In MySQL, I have a table with the following definition

```
CREATE TABLE `enterprise_rma` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'RMA Id',
  `status` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Status',
  `is_active` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',
  `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',
  `date_requested` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'RMA Requested At',
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order Id',
  `order_increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Order Increment Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_custom_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Custom Email',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_STATUS` (`status`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_IS_ACTIVE` (`is_active`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_INCREMENT_ID` (`increment_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_DATE_REQUESTED` (`date_requested`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_ORDER_ID` (`order_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID` (`order_increment_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_ENTERPRISE_RMA_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ENTERPRISE_RMA_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ENTERPRISE_RMA_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='RMA LIst';
```

I'm trying to `DROP` this table, but whenever I do I receive the following error.

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

What I don't understand is, the table **is already empty**.  If I `SELECT * FROM enterprise_rma;`, no rows are returned (`0 rows affected`)

[image]

and `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` returns nothing useful.

I know I can work around this with the following

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
DROP TABLE enterprise_rma;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

But I don't understand how a foreign key constraint could fail if there's no data in the table.  Is there a subtlety of MySQL's foreign key mode I don't understand?  Can MySQL get damaged or put in an invalid state when this happens?  Are there methods for troubleshooting this myself?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to drop a table that is the parent of another dependent table, even if it has no data. Because if you drop the parent, then you will *never* be able to insert any data in the child. You must first drop any child tables that reference `enterprise_rma`.

Something doesn't match your description, though. You said you were having trouble dropping the table, but your example about the foreign key checks shows you using `DELETE`.

`DELETE` is not the same as `DROP TABLE`. After `DELETE`, there are no rows in the table, but the table still exists. After `DROP TABLE`, the table doesn't exist, i.e. it doesn't show up if you run `SHOW TABLES`.

Comment: Thanks Bill, derpy morning. This particular database has had a lot of other integrity issues so I assumed it must have been something like that.